# Laravel 4 beanstalkd exception catching issue in job processing

Tags: laravel-4, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I am using beastalkd for the job queue processing email validations.

job processor implementation is like

```
public function fire($job, $data)
{

    // processing

    try {
       //some processing including some smtp simulation checks

    } catch (Exception $e) {
       //saving some status
    } 

    //further processing

    $job->delete();
}
```

Like the example above at some point there is an exception throwing which is indented to happen as per the process. The exception is catching properly and doing some actions in  catch block. The problem is after catching the exception that released back onto the queue.

Is there any way to continue processing the current attempt of the job even after the exception catches. ?

Comment: Can you post your `catch()` code? The issue might be in there.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange here the catch code

catch (Validate_Email_Exception $e) {
                    $email->setStatus('unknown');                    
                    continue;
}